# Check if the input matches the data in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 inputs.

```
<input maxlength="40" type="text" style="width:250px;height:50px;font-  size:20px;margin: 0 auto;margin-top:5px;" name="usernameInput" />
    <input maxlength="40" type="text" style="width:250px;height:50px;font-size:20px;margin: 0 auto;margin-top:5px;" name="passwordInput" />
    <input type="submit" />
```

And I have a mySQL database called log.
In log I have username and password.

What I want to do is that when a person tries to "login" then php checks if the username matches the input and then checks if in the same row the password matches the input.
How do I do it?

Comment: Please GOOGLE for some tutorials ..!! There are many example available on web!!

Comment: you can easily search tuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple thing is that you're going to have to search this up. There are many, many articles on how to get something from a MySQL database using PHP. Once you know how to retrieve something from a database, look up how to get things from POST. 
Once you know that, there should be no problem for you to find this out for yourself.

Comment: I know how to get data FROM the database and I know how to insert it, but this is my prob.